# Poisson equation with numerical right hand side

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-difference-method

I run into the following problem. Linear Poisson equation works OK, eg,

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == u[x, y], 
    u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
```

But if I change on the right hand side to numerically evaluated, `u[x, y]-> u[x, y]^(1.)` -  notice the point -

```
ufun = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == u[x, y]^(1.), 
    u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, 1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
```

I get error  messages.

Comment: It seems that Mma must understand `u[x, y]^(1.)` as a power which, though it is close to the unity, still it is not exactly 1. The equation, thus, becomes a nonlinear one. But nonlinear equations are not supported by Mma. I guess that this should be the problem.

Comment: Is there a simpler way around  (than writing elliptic solver from scratch)?

Comment: Yes, there is.  But I do not see, what is your problem. Why do you need to write `u[x,y]^1.` instead of `u[x,y]`?

Comment: I need to solve equation Laplacian[u[x,y]]= InterpolationFunction[x,y]. So, u[x,y]^1. is just an example of numerical, not analytic function on the right hand side.

Comment: Then you may make the following trick. Instead of your stationary equation try to solve a pseudo-time dependent one: `D[u[x,y,t],t]==Laplacian[u[x,y,t]]- InterpolationFunction[x,y]`, where `t` is the pseudo-time. It only has an auxilliary sense. The stationary solution you are after will be a fixed point of the dynamic solution of this equation. The pseudo-time-dependent equation can be solved by using the `MethodOfLines`. Have a look at tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines and Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve/Applications/PartialDifferentialEquation example 3 and 4.

Comment: Continuation: The important point is that this method enables one to solve nonlinear PDE, provided they are time-dependent. By solving it with a great enough value of the pseudo-time `t` you get close to desired stationary solution. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, will try.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch - what is a full link for Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/NDSolve/Applications/PartialD‌​ifferentialEquation example 3 and 4. Still have problems...

Comment: That is the full link. I do not understand your question.